# How can we solve single source destination graph with dijkstra?

Tags: dijkstra

I have a single destination and multiple sources and i want to go through all of the nodes, but here is the case of having single destination and multipe sources how can i solve this?
is there any way to modify it? may be i need jhonsons algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse all the edges from destination to the source.then you can apply dijkstra algorithm. you dont need jhonsons algorithm.